# Appending URL parameters to route without interupting current router action

Tags: angular, ngrx, angular-router

I have an Angular app that is typically routed to with a particular URL parameter,

```
http://example.com/mypage?myId=1234
```

However, when that parameter is not generated, I need to generate an id and add it to the url. So if you were to ever hit `http://example.com/mypage` without that parameter you would land seamlessly on `http://example.com/mypage?id=myGeneratedId`

I generate the ID at the app root with no issues, so then the next task is to add it to the URL. I have something like this where I hook onto the effect that generates the id to add it to the URL,

```
    public generateMyId$: Observable<Action> = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(GenerateMyIdEffect),
        switchMap(__ => {
            const id = generateId();

            return [
                SetId({ id })
            ];
        }),
        tap(action => {          
          this.router.navigate([], {
            queryParams: {
              id: action.id, 
            },
            queryParamsHandling: 'merge',
            replaceUrl: true
          }) 
        })
    ));
```

The issue is that Effect kicks off BEFORE the router is finished routing to `/mypage`. I can see in the dev tools that the routing action to `myPage` is canceled and replaced with the `router.navigate(...)` action in that effect. The impact is that the relative route I supply above `this.router.navigate(**[]**`, ends up being `/` instead of `/myPage` because it never finished routing to `myPage`.

You end up at,

```
http://example.com/?myId=1234
```

I can fix this simply by subscribing to router events and appending the id to the URL after each instance of `NavigationEnd`,

```
router.events.subscribe(event => {
      if(event instanceof NavigationEnd){ 
        this.router.navigate([], {
          queryParams: {
            id: '1234', 
          },
          queryParamsHandling: 'merge',
          replaceUrl: true
        })
      }
    }
```

That "works", but it is clunky. It is running far more often than it would ever need to and will force me to grab the id from state in a component that otherwise would not need access to state.

So, is there a way to more seamlessly add that query parameter to the URL without disrupting the current routing action?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use guard or resolver and make redirect to generated url from there.

Comment: Yea I considered this, it ends up being similar to the subscription solution though. I know that the only time I ever need to append this to the URL is after I have generated an id manually because we have already established that it is missing before we generate it. I was hoping to find a way to append the parameter immediately after generating an id at the app root because otherwise I have to add the resolver to every page and run code that checks if the id is already in the URL on each load.

Comment: And won't this still run into the same issue? The resolver is going to run before it is finished routing. So unless there is way to update the query parameters without calling .navigate() then this will have the same issue as above.